# DomDocument innerHTML does not work in simple php script

Tags: php

innerHTML in php DomDocument does not work in simple PHP script and I can't set the inner html of html element by id, There is no error/warning! what should I do ?

(I also checked the file name and the html element id)

```
    $index = new DomDocument;
    $index->validateOnParse = true;
    $index->formatOutput = true;


    $index->loadHTML('index.php');

    $index->getElementById('element-unique-id')->innerHTML = 'some text';


    echo $index->saveHTML();
```

the out put is blank.

Comment: [`DOMElement`](http://php.net/manual/class.domelement.php) (and by extension [`DOMNode`](http://php.net/manual/class.domnode.php)) does not have a property `innerHTML`. All you're doing is setting an unused, dynamic public property

Comment: By the way, you could check if `$index->saveHTML();` is false - it would mean an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there's no `inneHTML`-property, you can solve it by creating and appending a new `DOMText` node:

```
$index->getElementById('element-unique-id')
      ->appendChild(new DOMText('some text'));
```

See also [The DOMText class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domtext.php) and [DOMText::__construct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domtext.construct.php).